# Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property while the connection (state=Open)

Tags: c#, connection-string, delete-row, 3-tier

I'm creating 3-tier architecture windows application program, and this error shows every time I delete multiple rows in datagrid that are checked. The codes are as follows:

```
IN DAL:

    public void delete_contact(MySqlCommand cmd)
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = connString;

                if (ConnectionState.Closed == conn.State)
                    conn.Open();

                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = delete_proc;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            }

    DELETE BUTTON:
     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                addcon ac = new addcon();
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    isCellChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                    if (isCellChecked == true)
                    {
                        ac.snum = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                        ac.delete_proc();
                        MessageBox.Show("Deleted", "Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
            }
```

How to fix the error? Please help. Thanks

Comment: You fix the error when you stop using a global connection object and start creating and destroying the connection every time you need it. The using statement and the connection pooling will be used to solve your problem

Comment: When deleting an objects from a list you must start at the end of list and work towards the beginning.  If you delete item 4 then all the rows above drop by one number.  So use : for (int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)